# Remove Translucency of UIStatusBar

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar

I am trying to make my `UIStatusBar` not translucent at all.
While my `UINavigationBar` is completely white, I want the `UIStatusBar` to follow that behavior.

In my `appDelegate - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I was trying:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .Default
```

But there is no way for me to set e.g. the alpha or translucency.
Any ideas?

Comment: Don't you rather look for black color of your status bar text on white background?

Comment: yes i do! @pedrouan

Answer (score 1):

**1)** In your info.plist file insert a new record with key "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to NO

**2)** In case the previous step does not work:

In your `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method of the *AppDelegate.swift* file put

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent // or .default
```

**3)** Try this inside your controller:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .default
}
```

**4)** Put this in your viewDidLoad method:

```
self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

Comment: I have tried this, also with the plist. But I want it to be white with Black tint color

Comment: Answer updated. The code may differ as written in swift 3

Comment: what exactly is the 3rd step doing? im not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Put it inside your controller like you would put a new method. It is new mode of setting of preferred color in Swift.

Comment: I think you meant override method rather than var. It is not working unfortunately. It is still translucent.

Comment: No, it is supposed to be use as-is in the comment above. It is standard getter only variable. Read docs here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621416-preferredstatusbarstyle

Comment: Check my last answer update. :) maybe we forgot to put very important command.

Comment: sorry it is still not working. I am still getting an opaque status bar

Comment: Opaque is the opposite od translucent, isn´t it?

Comment: meant to write translucent

Comment: @JVS I have been confused, the param of a view controller status bar appearance should be set to YES, after I did additional research.